# Vulnerability of Cloud SQL on GCP

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform

I am now using Cloud SQL for MySQL on Google Cloud Platform.

The version of MySQL is "8.0.18".

Recently, I found that MySQL version 8.0.21 or prior had vulnerability for CVE-2020-14878.
https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2020-14878

My simple question is
Cloud SQL for MySQL (version 8.0.18) has patched for the CVEs such as above vulnerabilities?

Comment: It's related to LDAP auth. LDAP isn't used on Cloud SQL - MySQL. I think it's not applicable

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Thank you very much. It's very simple answer..!! It means that Cloud SQL ignores unrelated CVE cases..?

Comment: I can't speak for Google Cloud, but I would like to say yes. I will do the same in my datacenter: Patch the module, or deactivate it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with  guillaume blaquiere It's related to LDAP auth. LDAP isn't used on Cloud SQL, Cloud SQL ignores unrelated CVE cases.

For more information you can refer to the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/release-notes) on production update on Cloud SQL and [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center/docs/concepts-vulnerabilities-findings#sql-findings) on SQL vulnerability findings.

Comment: @dimpman Posted an answer, Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud SQL keeps on providing important patches, as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/db-versions#introduction).

However, if you are interested in anything in particular, its best to raise a [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/procedures#create_a_support_case) with Google Cloud.